# Bootcamp load at startup with VMware

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, vmware

I have bootcamp loaded with Windows and would like it to boot and login at startup through VMware Fusion instead of starting manually after OSX 10.6.7 loads.

- Any ideas on how this functionality can be turned on or off?

[image: Boot Camp Partition]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have setup VMware Fusion to run your Windows in Bootcamp, then you just have to do one of two options.

Right click on the VM to run when Fusion starts, and then select **Open When VMware Fusion Starts**.

[image]

or just select the star next to the VM in question.

[image]

Then the next you have to do is to add VMware Fusion to your Login Items - `System Preferences->Accounts->[THE LOGIN USER]->Login Items`